# Can't add OneDrive business account to OneDrive client

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, onedrive

I tried adding OneDrive for Business account like in this tutorial [MS OneDrive Tutorial](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-started-with-the-OneDrive-for-Business-Next-Generation-Sync-Client-in-Windows-615391c4-2bd3-4aae-a42a-858262e42a49?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). But I can't see any button.

[image: Missing button in my OneDrive client]

I have Office 2016 installed on Windows 10 Enterprise.

Comment: You have installed the [OneDrive for Business Sync Client](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=248256) right?

Comment: @Ramhound From my understanding. In Windows 10 it was already installed. It works now. Thank you. Post it as answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: You only wait 3 hours before you decided to cross-post?  I mean this question belongs here but 3 hours is nothing.